# Parse a string representing an array of floats

Tags: javascript, parsing, floating-point

I have a string as such:

```
string = "[x,y,z]"
```

Where `x`, `y` and `z` are valid javascript floats as strings. Some examples:

```
-0.9999
1.
1.00000000000E-5
-1E5
```

What is the most efficient (fastest) way to parse this string into an actual javascript array of floats **without using Eval**?

Now I do this:

```
parseFloatArray = function(string){
    // isolate string by removing square brackets
    string = string.substr( 1, string.length-2 )

    // create array with string split
    var array = string.split(',');

    // parse each element in array to a float
    for (var i = 0, il = array.length; i < il; i++){
        array[i] = parseFloat(array[i]);
    }

    // return the result
    return array
}
```

It is important that the solution works correctly for the above examples.

I also tried with `JSON.parse` which seemed perfect at first, but it returns a **SyntaxError** for the second example `1.` where there is nothing following the decimal separator.

I prepared **[a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/3vvaekka/1/)** for testing.

Comment: `1.` is not a valid float number, this is why `JSON.parse`returns an error.

Comment: `1.` is not a valid float

Comment: Hmm, but parseFloat works fine with it?

Comment: try this array[i] = +array[i]; here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gsppz9w7/ but i am not sure if its the best way to do it.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ @Jamiec `1.` is a perfectly valid float

Comment: @zerkms I sort of agree, in that `parseFloat` will accept it, but in no number system can a decimal place exist without a numeric after it. This problem is XY - fix whatever is producing an invalid(ish) string representing an array (or make it return an array not a string, for that matter!).

Comment: `1..toSource()` is valid JS code where `1.` is number and `.toSource()` is its method.

Comment: @RadekPech - er....[sure?](https://jsfiddle.net/yegkrvnm/)

Comment: @Cyril Nice one :)

Comment: @Jamiec Yes, if you have method toSource() then it works. You can try other methods, e.g. `1..valueOf()`.

Comment: @Jamiec That [example](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/yegkrvnm/1/) seems to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this

```
array[i] = parseFloat(array[i]);
```

try
  `array[i] = +array[i];`

Above handles all the test cases pretty well.

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsppz9w7/)

Comment: Would be interesting to see some numbers on the performance of this compared to `parseFloat` and `Number`. **jsPerf** is down for some time already, I should maybe do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
str = "[-0.9999, 1., 1.00000000000E-5,-1E5]";
str.slice(1, str.length-1).split(',').map(Number);
// [-0.9999, 1, 0.00001, -100000]
```

Answer (score 0):

parseFloat basic syntax is parseFloat(string). https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

If you think the input values are only numbers you can use Number(x) rather than parseFloat.

Also, you might get different values upon parsing because all floating-point math is based on the IEEE [754] standard. so use toPrecision() method to customize your values- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Number/toPrecision.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of you writing the for loop, you can always use the javascript built in array.prototypes

```
var string = "[1.,-0.9999,-1.00000E-5]";
var array = string.substr( 1, string.length-2 ).split(',');

console.log(array.map(function(i){return parseFloat(i);}));
```

you can also use the unary operator instead of parseFloat().

```
console.log(array.map(function(i){return +i;}));
```

Comment: I think `array.map( parseFloat );` would be enough, you don't have to wrap it in a function.

Comment: Yes. That is the short form of what I wrote. Internally this is process
`array.map(function(i){return parseFloat(i);})`

Answer (score -1):

Most efficient to extract is replacing and splitting.

```
var str = "[312.413,436.6546,34.1]"; // string

str = () => str.replace(/\[|\]/g, "").split(","); //[312.413, 4...] Array
```

most eficient to parse is just preceed the string with a "+", that will numerify it and, since javascript works with floats as primitives (and not integers), they will be automatically parsed.

```
var a = "1.00000000000E-5";
console.log( +a ); // 0.00001
```